# TypeError : Trouble accessing JSON metadata with Python

Tags: python, json

So I'm trying to access the following JSON data with python and when i give the statement :

```
print school['students']
```

The underlying data gets printed but what I really want to be able to do is print the 'id' value.

```
   { 'students':[  
                  {  
                     'termone':{  
                        'english':'fifty',
                        'science':'hundred'
                     },
                     'id':'RA1081310005'
                  }
               ]
   }
```

So when I do the following I get an error :

```
 print school ['students']['id']
```

TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Can anyone suggest how i can access the ID & where I'm going wrong!

Comment: `students` is a list of students, not a dictionnary. so `school["students"][0]['id']`

Answer (score 2):

`school['students']` is a list. You are trying to access the first element of that list and `id` key belongs to that element. Instead, try this:

```
school['students'][0]['id']
Out: 'RA1081310005'
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that in your list, `'id'` is not a part of a dictionary, it is part of a list. To fix this, change your dictionary to the following:

```
school = {'students':{
            'termone': {
                "english": "fifty:,
                "science": "hundred
            },
            "id":"RA1081310005"
        }
}
```

Basically, you have a list, and there is no reason to have it, so I removed it.